# Why am I not spawning where I expect with certain Minecraft seeds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I enter a custom seed for a village or a rainforest I always spawn in an area completely different. For example, I want a plains biome but I spawn into a desert. Is there something I'm missing? Do seeds just randomize for every computer?

The seeds I'm looking at are seeds that were discovered in 1.6. There are no special settings I'm entering.

Comment: That depends - what are you entering, and are there any applicable special settings? And what version were the seeds discovered in?

Comment: Quite often, suggested seeds for villages or whatever will spawn you some way away, and you'll need to make your way to the desired structure.

Comment: Guilo, do you know what a seed actually is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A seed in *Minecraft* is basically a random "code" that generates terrain. This "code" can be shared with others. However, seeds do not decide where the player spawns.

For example, if one player uses the seed "1337" and spawns in a desert that has a flat "plains" biome that is perfect for building on. However, if someone else enters the same seed "1337", they will get the same terrain, but spawn somewhere else on the world. All spawns are usually around the middle of the map, so if you don't see the landscape features that the seed is supposed to have, look around a bit; *it shouldn't be too far off*.

Also, keep in mind that some updates will "ruin" a seed. For example, back in the *1.5 beta* version of *Minecraft*, the seed "Glacier" used to spawn you around an area with huge mountains. Since then, updates to the world generator have been made, and the seed "Glacier" no longer creates a world with huge mountains.